# Google API PHP Update File

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm trying to update the content of the file. Use the PHP function:

```
function updateFile($service, $fileId, $newTitle, $newDescription, $newMimeType, $newFileName, $newRevision) {
    try {
        // First retrieve the file from the API.
        $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

        // File's new metadata.
        $file->setTitle($newTitle);
        $file->setDescription($newDescription);
        $file->setMimeType($newMimeType);

        // File's new content.
        $data = file_get_contents($newFileName);

        $additionalParams = array(
            'newRevision' => $newRevision,
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => $newMimeType
        );

        // Send the request to the API.
        $updatedFile = $service->files->update($fileId, $file, $additionalParams);
        return $updatedFile;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

....
$data = retrieveAllFiles($service);


$fileName = 'test.txt';
$mimeType = mime_content_type('./'.$fileName);


$res = updateFile($service, $data[0]['id'], $data[0]['title'], 'update', $mimeType, $fileName, true);
```

I'm trying to add a text file line "test string". Function updates the data file (description, lastModifyingUser...), but the content of the file remains the same. Who can tell what's wrong?

Comment: Try to send the same request in API explorer and see if you are able to see the update correctly. Here is the link for API explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Answer (score 0):

In additionalParams need to add :

```
'uploadType' => 'multipart',
or 
'uploadType' => 'media',
```

Hope it helps!